# SIGABRT when adding Cocoa WebView

Tags: cocoa

I have a very basic cocoa project. In fact, I haven't done anything at all yet. But when I add a WebView to the MainWindow and test the programme it keeps on jumping in the dock and Xcode says *GBD: Program received signal: "SIGABRT".* Am I missing something I have to do when using a WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you link against the WebKit framework?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I had to do that. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: I am having this same problem. How does one 'link against'?

Comment: Have you tried to research this? Research first then post your own specific question (like "How do I link a framework?"). Hint: that should be your search term and should produce many results since it's a FAQ.