# I get sigbart when webview is added in xcode; how do I link against WebKit Framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

[SIGABRT when adding Cocoa WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629392/sigabrt-when-adding-cocoa-webview)

This seems like it may answer my question but I don't know what it means to 'link against.'

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Just worked it out myself.

I need to include the webkit framework in my project.

See this link for instructions.

[How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4, select your project in the Project Navigator on the left.

Then in the main window, select "Build Phases".

The third section is "Link Binary With Libraries". Click on the "+" in the bottom left of this section, then you a list of available frameworks is available. You can select the WebKit framework here that will link it against your project.